# How can I use the calling file loop variable in another file (python)

Tags: python, variables, import

So, I have file **main.py**:

```
PB_array=['2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-01','2019-04-01']
for PB in PB_array:
    import anotherfile
```

**anotherfile.py**:

```
Filename=f"file-{PB}.tsv"
some functions...
```

How can I use variables "PB" in anotherfile?

Comment: It's not clear what your ultimate goal is, but maybe better to import functions from `anotherfile` and call them with `PB` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to call `import` inside a loop. The import will be done exactly once. You seem to misunderstand the purpose of the `import` statement in python. It is not an analog of the `source` command in a POSIX shell like bash. The solution is to put the code in module *anotherfile.py* into a function or a class method. Then call that function (or method) from the body of your `for PB in PB_array:` loop and pass `PB` as an argument to the function.